# Check if two cells match, but ignore spaces and periods

Tags: excel

I have a formula that is checking if two cells are the same.  For example:

```
 A1: Michael A
 B1: MichaelA
 C1: =IF(A1=B1,"Y","N")

 A2: Justin M.
 B2: Justin M
 C2: =IF(A2=B2,"Y","N")
```

With my current formulas, both C1 and C2 would return 'N' because of the periods and spaces.

Can I edit this formula to ignore them and return 'Y' on these occasions?

Comment: Are spaces and periods the only characters you want/need to ignore?

Comment: @Soulfire Yes.  I suppose commas could also cause some 'false negatives' for me but those are the only two I have noticed so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to ignore those and a formula is what you are after, you can nest substitutes and use an IF exactly as above:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I10," ",""),".","")=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J10," ",""),".",""),"Y","N")
```